How to get a formatted line from a dictionary var?
I'm pretty new to Ansible and I'm not sure how to get it right.
To start with, I have implemented this dictionary var for an exemple. There is 2 values but it could be a greater number:
tf_ETCD:
  1:
    hostname: Etcd01
    ip: 192.168.1.141
  2:
    hostname: Etcd02
    ip: 192.168.1.142

I'd like the result to be formatted like that:
{{ tf_ETCD1_Host }}=https://{{ tf_ETCD1_IP }}:2380,{{ tf_ETCD2_Host }}=https://{{ tf_ETCD2_IP }}:2380

So I kinda get it by looping over the list via this code:
    - name: Format each value
      set_fact:
        etcd: "{{ item.value.hostname }}=https://{{ item.value.ip }}:2380,"
      loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.dict', tf_ETCD) }}"
      register: etcd_query

    - name: Examine the joined string
      debug:
        msg: "{{ etcd_query['results'][0]['ansible_facts']['etcd'] }}{{ etcd_query['results'][1]['ansible_facts']['etcd'] }}"

The result gave me:
TASK [Format each values] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [] => (item={'key': 1, 'value': {'hostname': 'Etcd01', 'ip': '192.168.1.141'}})
ok: [] => (item={'key': 2, 'value': {'hostname': 'Etcd02', 'ip': '192.168.1.142'}})

TASK [Examine the joined string] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [] => {
    "msg": "Etcd01=https://192.168.1.141:2380,Etcd02=https://192.168.1.142:2380,"
}

I cannot figure out how to do a "foreach loop result" in my "Examine the joined string" play.
If you can give me a hint or the concept I'm looking for, you'll save my day.

"I'm not sure how to get it right.", there will not be the one right way, there will be many ... Whereby some might be simpler or less costly.

Figure out how to do a "foreach loop result" in my "Examine the joined string" play ...
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    tf_ETCD:
      1:
        hostname: Etcd01
        ip: 192.0.2.1
      2:
        hostname: Etcd02
        ip: 192.0.2.2

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ tf_ETCD[ansible_loop.index] }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, tf_ETCD | length, 1) | list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

  - set_fact:
      etcd: "{{ etcd | d('') + tf_ETCD[ansible_loop.index].hostname ~ '=https://' ~ tf_ETCD[ansible_loop.index].ip ~ ':2380,' }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, tf_ETCD | length, 1) | list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ etcd }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg:
    hostname: Etcd01
    ip: 192.0.2.1
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg:
    hostname: Etcd02
    ip: 192.0.2.2

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Etcd01=https://192.0.2.1:2380,Etcd02=https://192.0.2.2:2380,

Some Hints

How to count the number of elements in an array in Ansible?
Ansible loop in range
Use a default if a variable is not defined
Best practice to concatenate strings in Ansible variables: Using one Jinja2 expression or multiple?
Extended loop variables


Thank you for your answer. It work like a charm. I learn that loop can get a range with a loop control. Thanks a lot for your refs. your 1st link should have be my search to start with...
Have a good day :)
